# Must one leave France immediately after quitting one's job?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, france, working-visas, ofii

I am an Indian citizen in France on a VLS-TS scientifique-chercheur visa. I am a post-doctoral researcher, on a 1-year contract. The visa is valid from 2015 September, upto 2016 August. I have a OFII sticker, valid for the same period. I have a convention d'accueil from the university which was used to get the visa. If I quit my job now, can I stay on in France for a month or two, as long as the visa is valid, before leaving France?

I am not interested in unemployment benefits, and will not take up another job in France. I want to continue staying in France for a month or two on my own expense. I will certainly leave France before 2016 August. Is this possible?

Note: I'm asking this here instead of on expat.SE since the question is primarily about a short, almost "tourist-like" stay, not the longer period of employment (but still only 7 or 8 months) before it.

Comment: Would the close voter care to explain the vote despite the note the OP added about Expats.SE ?

Comment: I think this is still an expats question, as it relates to the conditions of a longer-term work visa at the end of employment

Comment: @blacbird57  it's an Expats question as it's about the intricacies of French residency laws.